# Where Do I Change version number in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, build, version

I have a IOS app released in the app store, using Cordova.

Now, I made several changes, but it seems that I cannot update the app in apple store, because (it's submitting with the same version number):

[image]

How do i update the version numbers in xcode so I don't get this error?

I searched the version number in the whole (Cordova) project and I did not found results, so question is:

How Do I change this value? ( either from the cordova project (platforms/ios) or the xcode project )

And I have this way setted in Xcode (obviously changing the "mybundle" for the right one:

[image]

But the error still referencing the previous  (published last year) version

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The version and build number is present on `info.plist`. If you open this file, you'll see two entries related to versioning

- Bundle version string (short)
- Bundle version

Another option is to click on the root on xcode project navigator, you'll see two text boxes to edit the same information (`Version`, `Build`)

[image]

For sure Cordova IDE offers another way to do it.

Comment: "The other option is to click over the project on project navigator", but where? ( sorry been using xcode only to release previous version ), thanks for you input

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet, added a screen capture

Comment: OK, I tried changing those values last night ( setting version and build to: 1.200001, and still having the same issue, any other thought? Thanks, again

Comment: `1100001` is greater than `200001`. You need to pick a greater number as new version, any. For instance `2000001`

Comment: You mean greater by longer (in this case)?

Comment: I changed to 1.200001111 and same result :S

Comment: What's the error now? `200001111` is definitively greater than `1100001` (numeric comparison)

Comment: Same error message because it seems to submit the question posted version !

Comment: Can you add a screen capture of your current version and build settings?

Comment: before my last comment I edited my question with "that" screenshot, is hat it?

Comment: I don't understand... on the sreenshoot still says version = `1.2000001` and not `1.200001111`..... You need to put in there something greater than `1. 1100001`

Comment: oohps, it was the earlier screenshot. but I updated it

Comment: They must have changed this because the "General" tab that you have selected in your screenshot is no longer an option after clicking on the root of the directory. Do you know where to find this now?

Answer (score 8):

**Change from the Info.plist file**

[image]

Comment: This is covered in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of changing it on the Xcode project, try changing it in the `config.xml` file.

```
<widget id="com.test" version="1.3" ios-CFBundleVersion="1.200001111" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
</widget>
```

`version` sets the `CFBundleShortVersionString` (release version), and `ios-CFBundleVersion` sets the `CFBundleVersion` (build version)

Then run `cordova prepare`

Answer (score 3):

Since the previous answers seem to be out of date, the place where you can now change this is under your Target > Build Settings > Versioning section

It should look something like this:

[image: Versioning section on the Build Settings tab]

Here you can find most of the version numbers you are interested in.

Answer (score 2):

I have also followed the above accepted answers just to add with a bit more clarity with this **Xcode** `Version 14.2 (14C18)`  and I have followed below steps

**Step - 1:** From **Xcode left side pane** options select **show project navigator**

**Step - 2:** Then select the project you have in my case its **AnimationApp** so I clicked on it from left side project navigator options

**Step - 3:** Then from the right side select **General** tab and follow the **Identity category** options form where we can change the **Version** and **Build** which is **1.0.0** and **1** in my case as can be found below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround; Open Xcode, go to "Runner (Project root)" -> "Build Settings: and, in the filter search, write the the current version of the app. All the instances of that version will appear, including `FLUTTER BUILD NAME` and `FLUTTER BUILD NAME NUMBER` and you can change them from there.

[image: Check attached image]

Comment: alektech, instead of posting an answer which is [identical to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77363419/16343464), please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, i'm new to stackoverflow, i just tried to help as many people as i can.