# Where do I change version and build number in xcode >= 12.3

Tags: xcode, versioning

After updating to xcode 12.3. I cannot find the settings for build and version numbers.
The xcode help itself also still has directions to the old project editor window and settings.

Has anyone found this yet and would be so kind as to tell me where?

Attached is what my project editor looks like. Nothing called 'Identity', 'Version' or 'build' - also not in the 'Build setting' or 'swift package' tabs.

This is what my project editor looks like:
[image: This is what my project editor looks like]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where Do I Change version number in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945031/where-do-i-change-version-number-in-xcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have selected now is the project. Under "bodycontrol" you should select the target for the platform, then you'll get the build & version number back

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround, Open xcode, go to Runner(Project root) -> build settings and in the filter search write the the current version of the app.
All the instances of that version will appear including FLUTTER BUILD NAME and FLUTTER BUILD NAME NUMBER and you can change them from there.
[image: Check the attached image.]