# How to manually manage Bundle Version for ios app extensions?

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I have simple app extension for my main ios app. And within its own info.plist there is a following line:

[image]

But whenever I delete it, it is automatically added here again. As of I use fastlane for CI/CD:

```
set_info_plist_value(
    path: INFO_PLIST_PATH,
    key: "CFBundleVersion",
    value: build_number
)

set_info_plist_value(
    path: SHARE_INFO_PLIST_PATH,
    key: "CFBundleVersion",
    value: build_number
)
```

As a result I get the following warning from CI command line:

> The CFBundleVersion of an app extension ('123') must match that of its containing parent app ('3393').

I am pretty sure it is set 3393 for both of them ( I have confirmed it), but it is later changed by xcode itself.

Is there a way to turn it off? And let me manage it manually?

Comment: Do you maybe have an xcconfig that overrides the version?

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer fixed it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75339532/6396924

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe you should remove that the Bundle Version line. It's a required setting in the Info.plist file (the Info tab in as shown in your screenshot) and Xcode will attempt to fix it by replacing that line.

Previously, the Bundle Version was set in the Info.plist file but not sure when, Apple have change the setting to reside in the xcproject file and use a variable in the Info.plist to point to the actual setting in the xcproject file. Even so, that line is required in the Info.plist file.

From your question, I surmises that you just want to set the Bundle Version to match the main app? If so, you should change the version in the General tab instead of the Info tab. Like here (note the `Build` field is the Bundle Version):

[image]